# List View items not visible after fragment view recreate

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview, recreate

I have a listview in my project.
On initial launch,my listview's data is visible.However when ever my views get recreate after coming from background after a long time,my listview's items doesn't showup.
Although,data is being set in listview and even my custom adapter's getView() method is also called(I verified it by printing log in getView). Still i am unable to see the items.

Data gets displayed on other views(Ex. TextView,Images,etc) in my layout,issue is only with the ListView.I even tried using Recycler view.
The issue still exists.
I wonder what exactly is happening to my adapter/listview.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: if possible can you post code of your adaptor class and activity class